# When calling the graph endpoint I get [NULL] in return

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

When calling the graph endpoint https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/[User] we get “null” for preferredLanguage. This is for both synced and cloud users. The local AD has the correct value and retrieving users by PowerShell also returns what is expected.

Please advise

Comment: What permission are you using to get users? I think you'll need [`User.Read.All`](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/permissions_reference#user-permissions) to read more than just basic information about users.

Comment: @Anders365 Please update the title to be more detailed on the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As Dimitry said in comments, the problem is in permissions.

You should add [User.Read.All](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/permissions_reference#user-permissions) as an Application permission to get preferredLanguage and other properties.

If you are logged in as a standard user (not an admin) and using Delegated permissions only, graph will return the value of preferredLanguage only for the user who has been granted permissions.